# Delta function potential, bound state energies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, dirac-delta-distributions

A lot of books find the bound state energies of the single delta function potential centred at $x=0$ by integrating the Schrodinger equation around $x=0$, using symmetric limits and making the width zero.

By heuristic argument it should not be equal to zero as the function is even.

Check

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E0+integrate+exp(-%7Cx%7C)+dx+from+-infinity+to+infinity

Please, let me know what is wrong or if there is some technicality with respect to theory of distributions playing around here.

Comment: You are integrating over the whole space whereas you need to integrate from $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$ about the discontinuity so that, with $\epsilon\to 0$, you capture the change in $\psi'$ across that discontinuity.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential

Comment: What exactly is your question?